# Oracle procedure not updating table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am running a simple procedure but with commit, but it does not work.

No SQLERROR is given.

```
PROCEDURE change_status (id NUMBER, status number) IS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CHANGING STATUS TO: '|| status || ' id '|| id);
  update STATISTICS_HANDLER sh set sh.status = status where sh.id = id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CHANGING STATUS TO: AFTER UPDATE '|| status || ' id '|| id);
commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INSIDE change_status EXCEPTION ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, changing `sh.status = status` to `sh.status = 8` (for example). Works great.

Thanks in Advance - I am breaking my balls for 3 hours now.

Tried the following:

```
EXECUTE PKG_STATISTICS.change_status(1223,5);
```

and

```
BEGIN
  PKG_STATISTICS.change_status(1223,5);
END;
```

and there is a line in `STATISTICS_HANDLER` with id `1223`.

SOLUTION:
Changing variable name from status to something else (not a column name) did the work.

Comment: The usual convention is to prefix parameters with `p_` (for "parameter") or `i_`/`o_` ("in/out") etc. Alternatively you can use the procedure name itself with dot notation, e.g. `change_status.status` refers to the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Oracle can't correctly execute the update query because you are using the same procedure param with the same name as the column names.

```
PROCEDURE change_status (in_id NUMBER, in_status number) IS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CHANGING STATUS TO: '|| in_status || ' in_id '|| in_id);
  update STATISTICS_HANDLER sh set sh.status = in_status  where sh.id = in_id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CHANGING STATUS TO: AFTER UPDATE '|| in_status || ' in_id '|| in_id);
commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INSIDE change_status EXCEPTION ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: I was able to understand it alone after a lot of time. Thanks you very much for spending time to my question.